# How to solve $k\ \cos(x)-(k+1)\sin(x) = k$ such that the solutions differ by $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to determine the parameters $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the equation 
$$k\ \cos(x)-(k+1)\sin(x) = k$$
has two solutions that differ by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

In general, I solve an equation of the form $a\cos(x) + b\sin(x) = c$ by dividing it by $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Then the equation can be rewritten in the form

$$\sin(x+\theta) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

In this case $\sin(x+\theta) = \frac{k}{\sqrt{2k^2+2k+1}}$, where $\cos(\theta) = \frac{k}{\sqrt{2k^2+2k+1}}$ and $\sin(\theta) = \frac{-(k+1)}{\sqrt{2k^2+2k+1}}$. Can someone help me to continue ? Does someone know a better approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hack: what if cos(x) = 1, sin(x)= 0 ? // Also, in this case, $k(cos(x) - 1) = -k\,2sin^2(x/2) = 2(k+1)sin(x/2)cos(x/2) = (k+1)sin(x)$. Thus $sin(x/2)(ksin(x/2) + (1+k)cos(x/2)) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to achieve

$$\begin{cases}k\cos(x)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -(k+1)\sin(x)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ = k,\\
k\cos(x+\frac\pi2)-(k+1)\sin(x+\frac\pi2)= k\end{cases}$$

or

$$\begin{cases}\ \ \ k\cos(x)-(k+1)\sin(x) = k,\\
-k\sin(x)-(k+1)\cos(x) = k.\end{cases}$$

By summing the squares,

$$k^2+(k+1)^2=2k^2,$$

i.e.

$$k=-\frac12.$$

This is a necessary condition.

Comment: Many thanks for this elegant and simple approach !

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $x=2y\implies $

$$\sin2y=k(\cos2y-\sin2y-1)$$

$$\implies2\sin y\cos y=-2k\sin y(\sin y-\cos y)$$

Clearly one of the roots is $\sin y=0,y=n\pi,x=2y=?$

So, the other value of $x$ should be $2n\pi\pm\dfrac\pi2$

Comment: Right, but you should consider that after simplification by $\sin y$, the resulting equation might still have two roots.

Comment: @Yves, onrbof them is not finite, right?

Comment: I have not attempted to solve that one, I am just raising the objection that the roots are not necessarily produced by $\sin y=0$, another option remains and deserves to be at least reported.